# Filtering mulit-sheet data document with use of advanced filter vba

Tags: excel, vba

At work I was asked to create Excel doc for filtering data. I've stumbled upon some difficulties with certain filter as described below.

Basically I have a document listing all the available weapons in a certain game. Each weapon is obtainable at some point in the game, for example weapon 1 can be obtained in mission 1 in act 1. I need to filter this data to allow searching for **all the weapons needed up to and including this certain Mission or certain Act.** So If I select e.g. **Mission 3** I need to display all the weapons **for Missions 1 2 and 3**. Same mechanic for acts. I was able to create horrible workaround for acts involving `if` statements but we have around 30 missions in the game, so doing the same for missions would be very repetitive.

In order to better explain my problem I have created a [small Excel document with example data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5sr8ywsKrisQzY5TThwVmRLUkk), it reflects the real document 'mechanics' that I implemented 1 to 1.

To break it down, after you open it you will see three sheets:

**Filter** - That's the one in which filter results are displayed.

**Full list** - That's the whole list of weapons that we want to filter.

**AM** - It's the list of Acts and Missions for the game.

I'm using this macro for filtering acts (it starts after you click Filter acts button):

```
 Sub FilterActs()
    Sheets("Filter").Select
    Range("B10").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Clear

    Sheets("Full list").Range("A1:H175").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:= _
        Sheets("Full list").Range("P1:P4"), CopyToRange:=Sheets("Filter").Range("B10"), Unique:=True
    Columns.AutoFit
    Range("B10").Select    
End Sub
```

It's working for acts because of the IF statements which you can find in the **Full list sheet, P1:P4**. However I can't figure out the way to do this automatically for missions without using gazilion IF statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a solution using your sample workbook. Please test this and see if it accomplishes what you intend:  http://excelhero.com/samples/roff_excelhero.xlsm

Please notice that this solution uses a different criteria range.

The relevant code from the solution is here:

```
Public Sub Filter()
    Dim rData As Range, rCrit As Range, rOut As Range
    With Sheets("Full list")
        Set rData = .[a1].CurrentRegion
        Set rCrit = .[s1:t2]
    End With
    Set rOut = [b10:d10]
    rOut(1).Select
    rData.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, rCrit, rOut
End Sub
```

Comment: It's very close to being perfect, however there's one problem, I assume it's due to fact that in my example document missions are named like mission 1 mission 2 mission 3 etc. meanwhile in real document it looks more like say: Prologue, Rescue, Reset, Bomb, Airport, Evacuation. So If I select Prologue I only want weapons needed for Prologue mission, but If I select Bomb I want weapons list for all prologue, rescue, reset and bomb missions. I don't think your solution is working correctly in such case. However I will check tommorow in the morning at work. Thanks for great input either way!

Comment: Yes, this will be a problem, since it is doing the comparisons lexicographically. We'll need to have a separate Mission Order column (this only needs to be in the Full List sheet) with numbers that can be used by the filter instead of the mission names.

Comment: If you provide me with such a list, I'll fix this problem for you.

Comment: Also, will there be a similar problem with the Acts? Are there ever more than nine Acts? Already there is DLC bust it is lexicographically after Act so not currently a problem.

Comment: In the best variant Acts are Act I, Act II, Act III, DLC (being filtered out as only DLC stuff without stuff from acts) and All for listing everything regardless if act/dlc/whatever. With missions it's currently 26 missions, I can't list them as I'm under NDA, but their names would be something like those above - "Prologue", "Rescue", "City evacuation", "Kill the X", "Recon" etc. So they are definitely not lexicographically sorted at all. and an "All" button for missions would be great aswell. Than you so much for doing this.